# avoid postback dynamically created checkbox in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

Within a web form I am dynamically creating a series of chekboxes that are added to an asp:panel.Where as the panel in reside into a update panel.I want to avoid postback on checkbox changed event fire.

my code snippet:

Aspx code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>
     <asp:Panel ID="pnlCuisine" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
  </ContentTemplate>
```

C# Code:

```
public static CheckBox[] chkbx = new CheckBox[15];
public static Label[] lblCuisine = new Label[15];
private void LoadCuisine(string searchStr)
    {
      .....
      .....
      .....
            int i = 1;

            foreach(var item in cuisineList)
            {
                chkbx[i]=new CheckBox();
                chkbx[i].ID = item.CategoryName;
                chkbx[i].Text = item.CategoryName;
                chkbx[i].AutoPostBack = true;

                lblCuisine[i] = new Label();
                lblCuisine[i].ID = "lblCuisine" + Convert.ToString(i);
                lblCuisine[i].Text = "(" + item.Count + ")";

                chkbx[i].CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(chkbx_CheckedChanged);

                pnlCuisine.Controls.Add(chkbx[i]);
                pnlCuisine.Controls.Add(lblCuisine[i]);
               pnlCuisine.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));
                i++;
            }
}
   void chkbx_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string searchString = ((CheckBox)sender).ClientID;
        populateGrid(searchString);
    }
```

Comment: You could read this, Maybe helps http://forums.asp.net/t/1604581.aspx/1 becouse the page says that you need to create the control every time that you do a postback.

Comment: @ababil,without postback how will your `chkbx_CheckedChanged` be fired. in that case, you will have to make `postback=true`. In case, you dont want the entire page in be reloaded then probably put your dynamic chkbox part in a frame and have that frame to be reloaded instead of the whole page.

Comment: Thanks for response.I have done my job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change this line of code

```
chkbx[i].AutoPostBack = true;
```

to

```
chkbx[i].AutoPostBack = false;
```

then you can avoid auto post back on checkbox changed event fire

Comment: can't do this.After clicked on checkbox data will be populate with filtered.